# Java Spring address of page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am really confused how does the address of my spring application come from.
I followed the tutorial, but now I am trying to change the address, but I can't find the spot.

At the moment address is this : http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/

Where can I change HelloWorld to something else?

I will provide you with any code you need. I have two conf files : web.xml, spring-servlet.xml, but there is nothing in them that contains `HelloWorld`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="hello.spring3.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" 
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="spring3" version="3.0">

    <display-name>Spring display name</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    </web-app>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually this is not issue unless you deploy it on production environament.

When you deploy it there you should create new HOST in TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml file

it should look something like:

```
<Host name="www.mysite.com" appBase="www"   
      unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"  
      xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">  
</Host>
```

Second option is to deploy your war file in ROOT directory, but in my opinion the first option  is more suitable.

**Update:** No problem, If you are using eclipse, please click right mouse button on your project, Select Properties - > Web Project Settings. 
and change name of your "HelloWorld" directory.

Comment: But i dont have it on production environment. I just run my spring project on tomcat.. How i can change the url then?

Comment: Weird, I changed it from HelloWorld to test, but still did not work. But then I dicovered on my workspace a "Servers" project, opened server.xml from there and changed path here     `<Context docBase="FormsHelloWorld" path="/Hello" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:FormsHelloWorld"/></Host>`

Comment: Maybe I can change from Web Project settings, when I am adding new project, but when my Project is already added to servers, then I can't change it. Only manually from tomcat config server.xml

Answer (score 1):

It's the name of your war file.

Comment: But where is the war file? I am just running the project on my tomcat, I am not deploying it or anything...How did the war get `HelloWorld` as its name?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure, I think I did not build, just have controller and few xml files and chose from Eclipse -> right click on project -> run on server  and profit.

Comment: You always build. Otherwise you would not have any compiled classes. :) I'd recommend to try danny.lesnik's suggestion above.